# Are sentences limited to one coordinating conjunction?

Tags: commas, coordinating-conjunctions

I have a sentence, and I'm not sure if it should be written as in example one or two:

Example one:

> Someone keeps on popping my car's tires. So I installed a camera onto my car, and I caught the guy.

Example two:

> Someone keeps on popping my car's tires[,] so I installed a camera onto my car, and I caught the guy.

As shown in my two examples, one of them has a comma before "*so*." So, which would be the better sentence?

Comment: Better than what?

Comment: I would use the second version, and eliminate the comma after "car".

Answer (score 1):

**Both your examples are equally correct.** This is an emphasis issue. Do you want the reader to experience a full stop? Then use a period.

You may be confused with serial conjunctions, which don't take commas:

*I like red and white and blue and purple.*

However, the writer may still use a comma to help with comprehension:

*I like red and white, or blue and purple*. Although some would use an em-dash there.

Answer (score 0):

As the question was put, stick to the second option.

Several other points in those examples need attention but in the context of the question as put neither is strictly wrong but Example Two is at least 99% preferable.